# How to make a regex for a string followed by Date

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to create a regex for folliwing string

```
Daily_Batch_summary_001_SS11_20181107165728.log
Monthly_Batch_summary_002_SS11_20181107165811.log
```

Now I know that **`_Batch_summary_`** and **`_SS11_`** is always going to be common.

The regex I ended up with is **`_Batch_summary_001_SS11_(\d+).log$`**
now I dont know what to use in the start of regex to represent as you can see Daily, Morning this word may change. also **`001`** , **`002`** is changing so I need some trick for those too

Any help would be appreciated, and my apology if I have missed something in explaining my problem.

Comment: Try `^([^_]*)_Batch_summary_(\d+)_SS11_(\d+)\.log$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JFwbmj/2).

Comment: I see the three digit number after `summary_` seems to vary.  Are you sure that `_Batch_summary_001_SS11_` is always the common prefix?

Comment: o yes you are right I have updated my question, thanks Tim

Comment: WIKtor, Thankyou, I dont know how to accept you answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match any amount of chars other than `_` with `[^_]*`, and to match 1 or more digits, use `\d+`:

```
^([^_]*)_Batch_summary_(\d+)_SS11_(\d+)\.log$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JFwbmj/2/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^_]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `_` (`[^_]` is a negated character class matching any chars but those defined in the class)
- `_Batch_summary_` - a literal string
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `_SS11_` - a literal string
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `log` - a literal string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: ok thankyou, Letme try and then I accept your answer, thanks for quick reply !

Comment: @Sara Note that the `.` char must be escaped if you want to match a literal dot in a string.

Comment: Yes I would definitely going to update answer, This regex doesnt bring the file tho, I dont know why